# Make a JsonConvert.DeserializeObject global(static)

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I use RestSharp to consume a Restful WCF, it works well in my subroute.

```
string baseUrl = "12.34.56.789/MyServices";
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://" + baseUrl + "/MyData.svc");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.Resource = "/GetProblemId";
request.AddParameter("problemId", "1");
var response = client.Execute(request);
var problems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProblemTypeDTO>>(response.Content);
```

Now I have to access problems in different method, so I want to set it as a global object.
But I can't declare it as

`private static var problems;`

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` can be used only inside methods. Fields should have a concrete type. In your case it is `List<ProblemTypeDTO>`

```
private static List<ProblemTypeDTO> problems;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not defining a type. You can't use var in a static field.

It should look as follows:

```
private static List<ProblemTypeDTO> problems;
```